# Searching for contact via contact email returns every contact for user in Outlook API

Tags: rest, outlook, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

Using `?$search="foo@bar.com"` in the URL query I am attempting to get full contact info for a contact matching that email address and am instead getting every contact for the logged in user.  The following query returns every contact for the logged in user including the one I want.

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/?search="ChristopherTEllingson@dayrep.com"
```

How do I get just the one contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a slight typo in your URL. You're missing a `$` in front of the `search` parameter, so it gets ignored. Try this:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/?$search="ChristopherTEllingson@dayrep.com"
```